# Does Crockford's "deentityify" method in The Good Parts actually work?

Tags: javascript, function, module

This particular code has been asked about twice before, but never was the question raised "does it actually do anything?". It appears in page 41 of Crockford's book.

Here is the syntactic sugar from earlier in the book:

```
Object.prototype = function (name, func){
    if(!this.prototype[name]){
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    }
```

and here is the deentityify methody:

```
String.method('deentityify', function ( ) {
    var entity = {
        quot: '"',
        lt: '<',
        gt: '>'
    };
    return function () {
        return this.replace(
            /&([^&;]+);/g,
            function (a, b) {
                var r = entity[b];
                return typeof r === 'string' ? r : a;
            }
        );
    };
}());
```

if in an editor your write something like:

```
document.writeln( '&lt;&quot;&gt;'.deentityify( ));
```

you'll see in the browser: 
however, if you type this in the browser:
    `document.writeln( '&lt;&quot;&gt;');`

you'll still see:

<">

I discovered that this method isn't actually replacing the entities when I attempted to use when pre-filling form data by setting the value field like this:

```
 var venueInput = document.createElement("input");           
        ...
        venueName = '&lt;&gt;&quot'; // for example
        venueInput.value = venueName.deentityify();
        form.appendChild(venueName);
        form.appendChild(venueInput);
```

Alert also show the entities aren't being replaced.

Can anyone help me see what I'm doing wrong? 
Thank you!

Comment: For folks who have not read the book, would you edit the question to explain what the this method is meant to do?

Answer (score 1):

After fixing some mistakes of the code you shared it works like a charm:

```js
Object.prototype.method = function (name, func){
    if(!this.prototype[name]){
        this.prototype[name] = func;
    }
}
  
String.method('deentityify', function ( ) {
    var entity = {
        quot: '"',
        lt: '<',
        gt: '>'
    };
    return function() {
        return this.replace(
            /&([^&;]+);/g,
            function (a, b) {
                var r = entity[b];
                return typeof r === 'string' ? r : a;
            }
        );
    };
}());
  
var venueInput = document.createElement("input");  
var label = document.createElement("label");
venueName = '&lt;&gt;&quot;'; // for example
venueInput.value = venueName.deentityify();
label.innerHTML = venueName;
document.getElementById('form').appendChild(label);
document.getElementById('form').appendChild(venueInput);
```

```html
<div id="form"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. In my code, I managed to mess up copying the RegEx and as a result wasn't matching the characters correctly. I'm just going to delete the question since the premise is wrong, misleading and generally not helpful for anyone else to read other than to serve as a reminder to thoroughly check code before asking the experts.

Answer (score 1):

> Here is the syntactic sugar from earlier in the book

You copied that incorrectly. It should look like this:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};
```

> > ```
> > venueName = '&lt;&gt;&quot'; // for example
> > ```

Entities should end with a ";". You forgot the one on quot.